# Why are all type bounds not used when inferring type constructors?

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, type-constructor

Consider the abbreviated output of `--explain-types` on the following snippet

```
scala> :settings --explain-types

scala> def f[F[_ <: Int] <: List[_ <: Int], A <: Int](as: F[A]) = as
def f[F[_ <: Int] <: List[_ <: Int], A <: Int](as: F[A]): F[A]

scala> f(List(42))
...
  List[A] <: List[_ <: Int]?
    Nothing <: A?
    true
    A <: Int?
    false
    List[_$1] = List[_$1]?
    true
  false
...
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : List[Int]
        required: F[A]
List[Int] <: F[A]?
false
```

My interpretation is that `List[A] <: List[_ <: Int]?` is false because

```
A <: Int?
false
```

but is it not the case that this type bound is given right there in the type clause

```
def f[..., A <: Int]
           \______/   
              |
         why is it not using this type bound?
```

Why is it not using `A <: Int` when `List[A] <: List[_ <: Int]?` is not satisfied to then try say `?F := [A <: Int] =>> List[A]` next?

Comment: Seems like a problem caused by the multiple constraints of upper-bounds. `def f[F[_ <: Int] <: List[_], A <: Int]` works fine